# throws are not catch when more than one thread run

Tags: multithreading, c++11, try-catch, throw

I have 2 threads, the main thread that is a producer, and a consumer. When the consumer throws an error, I pass it back to the main thread to throw it, but:

- Once the exception is received by the main thread, I cannot rethrow it without doing consumer.join() before, otherwise the exception is not catched.
- when an error from the main thread (that has nothing to do with the consumer) is thrown, it is catched only if the consumer has not been started (i.e ne thread is running).

it seems that all threads than the main one needs to be stopped to be able to catch errors. But it is weird. I won't add a "stopThread" function in all throws that are not related to the consumer.

I don't have code to show because this is a more general question and there might be some common rule that i don't know. don't hesitate if i lake informations.

Comment: AFAIK exceptions can't be thrown over thread boundaries. Are are you passing the exceptions between the threads? Also can you please try to create a [mcve] to show us, because from descriptions of unknown code it's impossible to understand what the code is  really doing.

Comment: Re, "I don't have code to show because this is a more general question." So, _write_ some code to illustrate it. If that's not possible, then the question probably is not appropriate for this site.

Comment: Passing exceptions between threads is certainly possible as it is what `std::future` and `std::promise` do by using `std::exception_ptr`. If that doesn't work on your side, then there's a bug in your code.

Comment: FWIW, Some programmer dude's assertion, "exceptions can't be thrown over thread boundaries," is a statement about the _act_ of throwing and catching an exception. A "catch" always happens in response to a "throw" _in the same thread._ Quentin's assertion about "Passing exceptions..." is talking about an exception _object_ (i.e., the _information_ that was thrown.) That object can be passed between threads just like any other object, and it can be _re-thrown_ in a different thread (e.g., when the second thread asks for the "value" of a `future` object that contains it.)